# how to truncate a character in string?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I need to truncate only the `s` letter in `https` can anyone help me how to truncate this from below string ?

```
https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/ewl_bannerslider/slides/5.jpg
```

Comment: Stop thinking of `URL`s as `String`s. Do you think of cars on the level nuts and bolts? Simple operations (change the url's scheme from `http` to `https`) become much harder when you're at the wrong level abstraction (think in terms of a `String`, rather than a `URL`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's easy to replace text inside a string with the help of the method [replacingOccurrences(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences) it is available from swift2 onwards.

```
let originalStr = "https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/ewl_bannerslider/slides/5.jpg"
let finalStr = originalStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "https", with: "http")
 print(finalStr)
```

**option2**

```
let str = "https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/ewl_bannerslider/slides/5.jpg"

    if str.utf16.count >= 5{
        let a = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
        let result =  String(str[..<a])
        let replaced = str.replacingOccurrences(of: result, with: "http")
        print(replaced)

    }else{
        //lenght in shorter
    }
```

**option3**

```
 var str = "https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/https/ewl_bannerslider/slides/5.jpg"
    str = str.stringByReplaceonFirstOccurrenceOfString(target: "https", withString: "http")
    print(str)



extension String
{
func stringByReplaceonFirstOccurrenceOfString(
    target: String, withString replaceString: String) -> String
{
    if let range = self.range(of: target) {
        return self.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replaceString)
    }
    return self
}
}
```

Comment: Please note that if there happens to be another instance of `https` in the string, it will be changed too, not just the one at the start.

Comment: may I know the reason of downvote, answer prodces multiple ways, if i made the mistake it will better to update

Comment: Not my downvote, but note that both your solutions will replace *all* occurrences of "https" in the string by "http", not only the initial scheme part.  For example, `"https://192.168.1.11/https/5.jpg"` becomes `"http://192.168.1.11/http/5.jpg"`, which is probably not intended.

Answer (score 5):

What you actually want is to change the scheme from "https" to "http" in an URL string. URLs can be safely manipulated using the `URLComponents` type:

```
var urlString = "https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/ewl_bannerslider/slides/5.jpg"

if var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: urlString), urlComponents.scheme == "https" {
    urlComponents.scheme = "http"
    urlString = urlComponents.string!
}

print(urlString)
// http://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/ewl_bannerslider/slides/5.jpg
```

If your intention is to create an URL request then you don't need
the modified string, but only the `URL(Request)` with the changed scheme:

```
let urlString = "https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/ewl_bannerslider/slides/5.jpg"

guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: urlString) else {
    // ... invalid URL string, bail out ...
}
if urlComponents.scheme == "https" {
    urlComponents.scheme = "http"
}
guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
    // ... invalid URL, bail out ...
}

let request = URLRequest(url: url)
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code snippet:

```
let tmpStr = "https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/ewl_bannerslider/slides/5.jpg"
      let modifiedStr  = tmpStr.replace("https", withString:"http")
    extension String
    {
        func replace(target: String, withString: String) -> String
        {
            return self.replacingOccurrences(of: target, with: withString, options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
        }
    }
```